# How to sum with a condition in regards to the merged header

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table whose headers are merged. So, its column are components of the merged headers.

I really don't know how else to describe the question without the help of the image attached. I'm really sorry. Basically, in the table, there are 3 kinds of fruit lovers. And for each type of fruit lovers there are subsets that describes the different size of each fruits they like. (Small/medium/big/petite).

Anyway, I want to find the sum of people who likes the different fruits in different cities. But I don't want to use the simple sum() because that would mean that I have to change the formula every time a new fruit size is added.

See, there are 3 kinds of fruit lovers right? I want to automatically generate the sum for different apple lovers in the table below for different city. Hence, i want the excel sheet to automatically know the range for apple lovers based on the table header with the name "apple lovers". so that next time if someone adds a new type of fruits, other than the "big/small/medium/petite", i want to this sheet to automatically know that okay the range of apple is from B3 to E3 based on the table header. Instead of Sum(b3:E3), i want to have a formula that does something like this sumif(b3:n3, header="apple lovers") for apples lovers in city A and sumif(b4:n4, header="apple lovers") for apples lovers in city B

and

sumif(b3:n3, header="orange lovers") for apples lovers in city A and so on. so if new type of fruits are created, no need update the formula.

[image: The excel sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the headers in your results table match precisely those in the source table, i.e. remove the "Total" part.

The formula in `B11` would then be:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$3:$A$5=$A11)*(LOOKUP(COLUMN($B$1:$N$1),COLUMN($B$1:$N$1)/($B$1:$N$1<>""),$B$1:$N$1)=B$10)*$B$3:$N$5)`

and copied across and down.